# The fact that subspace topology coincides with induced metric topology leads to a contradiction

Tags: general-topology

Let consider the subspace $A = [0,1] \cup \{3\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^1 $. We do now that the subspace topology on $A$ coincides with the induced metric topology on $\mathbb{R}^1$. (Usual Euclidean metric).

Now, this implies that 
$$\{3\} = B_{\mathbb{R}}(3,1) \cap A,$$
hence $\{3\}$ is open in $A$.

However, this implies $\exists \delta > 0$ s.t $B_{A}(3, \delta) \subseteq \{3\}$, and since we have found a open ball around $3$ that is contained in $A$, $3$ is an interior point of $A$, **but this contradicts** with what I have learned in my analysis courses (about the topology on $\mathbb{R}^n $), so what is the mistake that I'm doing in this argument ?

**Edit:**

Apparently, I wasn't realised that we define the concepts such as $closure, boundary, interior ...$ for **subsets** of a topological space, so after seeing this, the problems resolves itself.

**The question can be closed.**

Comment: What is the contradiction? $B(3,1) = \{3\}$. $\{3\}$ is also closed. Hence the set is disconnected.

Comment: @copper.hat but isn't 3 also in the boundary of $A$ ?

Comment: No, it is not contained in the closure of the complement (which is $[0,1]$).

Comment: The boundary is context dependent, you are asking boundary with respect to $A$ or ${\bf{R}}$?

Comment: @user284331 What do you mean by context dependent ?

Comment: @user284331 I'm talking about $\partial A$ in $\mathbb{R}^1 $

Comment: The boundary in $\mathbb{R}$ and the boundary in the induced topology on $A$ are two different things.

Comment: $\partial A = \bar A \cap \bar A^c$. Since $3 \in A \subseteq \bar A$, and clearly $3 \in (A^c)', 3 \in \partial A$.

Comment: Do you want to look at the subspace topology or not???

Comment: @copper.hat which one means what ? Could you explain ? because I do not understand what both of you are implying.

Comment: That is like saying that $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ is connected because it is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @Masacroso so what ? what disturbs me is that $3 \in Int (A)$ and $3 \in \partial A$, where these two sets should have been disjoint.

Comment: When you deal with the subspace $A$, only points in $A$ matter. In the subspace topology, $\overline{ \{3\}^c} = [0,1]$.

Comment: @copper.hat I guess that is analogous to "The boundary in $\mathbb{R}^1 $" ? What about the other case ?

Comment: It makes no sense to talk about $\partial A$ in the context of the subspace topology. $A^c = \emptyset$.

Comment: @copper.hat Then lets talk bout in the sense that $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^1 $,

Comment: There is no contradiction. You are confusing two things. $A$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $A$ as a topological space in its own right. The boundary of a topological space is always empty.

Comment: @copper.hat what about the boundary of a subspace in the sense that *it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R} $*.

Comment: @onurcanbektas: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: @copper.hat Apparently, I have misunderstood those concepts, thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question on OP's request as it was based on a false premise.

Answer (score 2):

$B_{A}(3,\delta)=\{x\in A: |x-3|<\delta\}$. For example, if $0<\delta<1/2$, then $B_{A}(3,\delta)=\{3\}$.

Answer (score 0):

$A\supset B_A(3,\delta)=\{3\}$ for $\delta \lt 2$...